# discord.py, using slash command and prefix at the same time

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How to run a slash command with a prefix at the same time in Discord? Bigger bots like mee6 have that you can use the prefix `!` and `/` at the same time, there is I think only one way to use slahscommands on discord.py and that is by using [discord-py-slash-commands](https://github.com/discord-py-slash-commands/discord-py-interactions), I tried many ways, but all didn't work, I tried using two @ like @cog_ext.cog_slash and @commands.command at the same time but for me that was logical to do, but that is only because I'm a beginner in python. When I run them in two separate cogs it says on the slash command `This interaction failed` or some kind of other error, so my question is if it is possible to have slash commands and a prefix running on one command, for example help(so I can do !help and /help), and if it is then how can I do it?

Comment: Your first question was closed, you shouldn't repost it. Stack Overflow isn't a code providing service, you need to show at least some [effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you came up with any code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the command twice, one with `@commands.command` and a second with `@cog_ext.cog_slash`

Maybe if the commands function is very long or you just do not want it twice you can spil it it into another funtion that you call with both commands

```py
async def cmd(author):
    # do your commands stuff here

@commands.command(name="cmd")
async def command_cmd(ctx):
    await cmd(ctx.author) # call the cmd function

@cog_ext.cog_slash(name="cmd") # I'm not 100% sure if it works like that since i 
async def slash_cmd(ctx):      # 
    await cmd(ctx.author) # call the cmd function
```

Comment: Thanks, and it was my mistake, I think it was my patience, because I already tried that, but when I put the command in discord it just failed again, but I forgot to invite the bot again(or I needed to wait). Sorry for the unnecessary post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the decorator @commands.hybrid_command

Example: `@commands.hybrid_command(name="commandname", description="Command description.")`